# Passing main arguments to init functions of gui libraries

Tags: c, qt, user-interface, gtk

When it comes to a library initialization in libraries such as Qt and GTK+
You have to pass the main arguments into the function that initializes the library. Why? What is the library doing with them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both Qt and GTK+ are designed to respond to certain command line flags for convenience.  (Both respond to various environment variables as well.)  You don't necessarily *have* to send argv and argc to the corresponding init functions, but it doesn't hurt, particularly if you intend to take advantage of the features.

Here's what the GTK+ [documentation for gtk_init() has](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk3-General.html#gtk-init) to say:

> Although you are expected to pass the argc , argv parameters from
>   main() to this function, it is possible to pass NULL if argv is not
>   available or commandline handling is not required.
>
> argc and argv are adjusted accordingly so your own code will never see
>   those standard arguments.

A full list of the command line options that GTK+ accepts [is here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-running.html).

Qt's QApplication similarly accepts command line arguments and removes the ones that it accepts.  This is documented along with the accepted arguments in the [QApplication constructor documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#QApplication).

Comment: The application may be even a command line app. That's why we have convenient `QCommandLineParser` class